# Add ckeditors fields dynamically in modal

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

i have a cms where on click open modal and inside i have few fields and then i have another button inside of modal where i can add dynamically ckeditors fields by clicking on button, here is what i was trying to do:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <button style="margin-bottom:5px;" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Adauga</button>
</div>
<div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">



  <!-- Modal content-->

  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">

      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

      <h4 class="modal-title">Adauga categorie</h4>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

      <div class="row">

       <div class="container">

          <form action="add.php" method="POST">

          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="input-1">Nume Categorie</label>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nume" id="nume" placeholder="Nume categorie">

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="input-1">Categorie</label>

              <select class="form-control" id="categorie" name="categorie">

                  <option value="0">Categorie principala</option>


              </select>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="input-1">Vizibil</label>

              <select class="form-control" id="activ" name="activ">

                  <option selected>Selecteaza vizibilitatea</option>

                  <option value="1">Da</option>

                  <option value="0">Nu</option>

              </select>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

              <label for="input-1">Pozitia</label>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pozitie" id="pozitie" placeholder="Pozitie">

          </div>

          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="icheck-material-primary">

                <input type="checkbox" id="user-checkbox1" checked="">

                <label for="user-checkbox1">Modele Produse</label>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="icheck-material-primary">

                <input type="checkbox" id="user-checkbox2" checked="">

                <label for="user-checkbox2">Paletar Materiale</label>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

              <div class="form-group">

                 <div class="icheck-material-primary">

                <input type="checkbox" id="user-checkbox3" checked="">

                <label for="user-checkbox3">Estimare Pret</label>

                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="rowa">

              <div class="add-plus">Adauga tab-uri</div>

              <div class="col-md-12">

                <span id="add_aut" class="btn btn-primary">+</span>

                 <div id="auth-rows"></div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

       </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Inchide</button>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Salveaza</button>

      </div>

       </form>

  </div>

</div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(e){

        // variable 

        var html3 = '<div class="row" id="parent-autor"> <p id="auth-del"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></p> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="titlu_tab" name="titlu_tab[]"> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pozitie" name="pozitie_tab[]"> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group"> <textarea name="editor[]" class="ckeditor" id="continut" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea> </div> </div></div>';


        $("#add_aut").click(function(e){

            $('#auth-rows').append(html3);

        });


        $('#auth-rows').on('click', '#auth-del', function(E){

            $(this).parent('div').remove();

        });
});

</script>
```

In this modal when i click on add i want to add more fields, is done this but not appear ckeditor just a plain textarea which i don`t need that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to want to give the textarea a custom id if you plan to have multiple of them.

```
let currentId = 0;
```

I moved the 'var html' code inside the create function so that we can edit the id every time the add button is clicked because we need a unique id each time. After the textarea exists, I call .ckeditor() on that textarea which should enable the ckeditor tools for that field. Then I increment the customId to make sure that the next form that is added has a different id.

```
$("#add_aut").click(function(e){

    var html3 = '<div class="row" id="parent-autor"> <p id="auth-del"><i class="fa fa-minus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></p> <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="titlu_tab" name="titlu_tab[]"> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-4"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pozitie" name="pozitie_tab[]"> </div> </div> </div> <div class="col-md-12"> <div class="form-group"> <textarea name="editor[]" class="ckeditor" id="continut' + currentId + '" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea> </div> </div></div>';
    $('#auth-rows').append(html3);
    $('#continut' + currentId).ckeditor();
    currentId += 1;

});
```

You may not want the customId in the id of the textarea depending on what you are trying to accomplish, but this should get you going in the correct direction.

Also, you need to add the ckeditor.js as well as a jquery adapter script for this to work.

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bkqxnu8f/3/